# .htaccess Redirect Directory To Subdirectory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdirectory

I am attempting to redirect my page

```
http://example.com/category/general/
```

to

```
http://example.com/blog/category/general/
```

I thought that this would work but it ends up endlessly looping

```
RedirectMatch 301 /category/general/ /blog/category/general/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use regex anchors as well:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/category/general/?$ /blog/category/general/
```

And with capturing groups:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(category/general/?)$ /blog/$1
```

Test this after clearing your browser cache.